# What are the rules for custom syntax declarations in Agda?

Tags: syntax, agda

The [Agda docs](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0.1/language/syntax-declarations.html) don't really have much to say on `syntax` declarations, and a cursory glance at the source code is less than illuminating, so I've been trying to piece it together myself using examples from the standard library like `Σ[_]_` and `∃[_]_`. I can reproduce an (admittedly rather contrived) example like theirs fairly easily

```
twice : {A : Set} → (A → A) → A → A
twice f x = f (f x)

syntax twice (λ x → body) = twice[ x ] body
```

But when I try to define custom syntax that binds two variables, I get an error

```
swap : {A B C : Set} → (A → B → C) → B → A → C
swap f y x = f x y

syntax swap (λ x y → body) = swap[ x , y ] body
```

Specifically,

```
Parse error
y<ERROR>
 → body) = swap[ x , y ] body
...
```

So I assume there are some rules as to what's allowed on the left-hand side of a `syntax` declaration. What are these rules, and what of them prohibits my two-variable lambda form above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Agda does not allow syntax declarations with multi-argument lambda abstractions. This is a known limitation, see the [issue tracker](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/394) for the corresponding enhancement request.